# Grid layout with search bar in header

Tags: css, layout, grid

I am trying to come up with a solution for advanced layout. I decided to use a css grid as it seemed to be the best match for my needs.

The requirements:

1. Header - consists of three elements - logo, search bar and menu

   - search bar should be aligned with the main content if space allows, i.e. on small screen search bar doesn't need to start where the main content starts but **it should end where main content ends or take all available space**
2. Main - consists of content and sidebar- should be centred and take max 100rem width space

   - content should be 2 times bigger than the sidebar
   - main content should have at least 1rem space from left and right

This is how it looks now. It matches my requirements on big screens (4k) but when the screen gets smaller it gets messy. I would really like to avoid any javascript and solve this with pure CSS if possible.

How would you approach this problem? I am now more inclining that this is not solvable with pure CSS and JS is needed. (Probably some resize observer on main-content element)

Examples:

- Big screen -> alignment is correct ✔️

[image]

- Small screen -> alignment is not correct. ❌ The search box should be within the black "brackets"
  [image]
- Even smaller screen -> alignment is not correct too. ❌ The search box should expand up to the black line
  [image]

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(1rem, 1fr) minmax(min-content, 100rem) minmax(
      1rem,
      1fr
    );
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    ". main .";
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  background: green;
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 1fr) minmax(min-content, 100rem) minmax(
      max-content,
      1fr
    );
}

.search-box {
  background: yellow;
  max-width: calc(2/3 * 100%);
}

.logo {
  background: yellowgreen;
  min-width: 5rem;
}

.menu {
  background: brown;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: flex;
}

.main-content {
  background: red;
  flex: 2;
}

.sidebar {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo">Logo</div>
      <div class="search-box">
        Search box should should match main content position
      </div>
      <div class="menu">Menu with two submenus at least</div>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
      <section class="main-content">Main content</section>
      <aside class="sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sandbox available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hopper-b8kgi?file=/styles.css)

Comment: hi, is this what you need? https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-surf-v3bqb?file=/index.html

Comment: there are a lot of ways to implement this, check out my link, if you want to style header and main tags you can make them grids as well

Comment: @Alopwer thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't match my requirements. I want to have a logo column to have a different width than a first column in the second row. See the third image in my question.